# PHP array with JavaScript objects to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, json

If I have an array in JS like this:

```
{
 "car": "BMW",
 "count": 7 
}
```

I can generate it from PHP quite easy using this array:

```
array(
       'car' => 'BMW',
       'count' => 7,
)
```

and json_encode. This is not a problem.

But what if I have an array in JS like this:

```
{
   "center": new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
   "zoom": 8
}
```

is there also some nice way how to produce it from PHP?

The method above fails because JSON put quotes around "new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)".

Comment: Your first example isn't an array, it's an object.

Comment: You are right, sorry for confusion. I'm more PHP than JS ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON doesn't support custom types. It's just meant for passing data and to be available to any consumer, whereas `google.maps.LatLng()` isn't really "*data*."

So, you'll have to accomplish this in 2 steps:

1. You can include the values needed in another PHP `array` for the JSON:

   ```
   array(
       'center' => array(
           'lat' => -34.397,
           'lng' => 150.644
       ),
       'zoom' => 8
   )
   ```

   ```
   {
       "center": {
           "lat": -34.397,
           "lng": 150.644
       },
       "zoom": 8
   }
   ```
2. Then, once parsed to a JavaScript `Object`, say `data`:

   ```
   data.center = new google.maps.LatLng(data.center.lat, data.center.lng);
   ```

   And, if there are numerous examples of such objects in the data, you can specify [a `reviver` `function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to try to recognize them and create the instances:

   ```
   // parse, creating `google.maps.LatLng` from any { lat: ..., lng: ..., ... }
   var data = JSON.parse(jsonString, function (key, value) {
       if (typeof value === 'object' && value.lat && value.lng) {
           return new google.maps.LatLng(value.at, value.lng);
       } else {
           return value;
       }
   });
   ```

   Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XXbUU/

---

Side note: JSON and JavaScript make a stronger distinction between "*array*" types than PHP does.

- "*Associative*" `array`s in PHP become `Object`s in JSON and JavaScript.
- "*Non-associative*" `array`s in PHP become `Array`s in JSON and JavaScript.

Comment: To elaborate on Jonathan's answer, you're trying to store functionality within JSON. JSON is used for structuring data, not executing it. `new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)` is functionality, and needs a processor to evaluate. JSON is processor-independent because it is just a string. Hence your way around would be to store the coordinates and then instantiate them when in the PHP/JS environments.

Comment: As another sidenote, this is a better practice than passing an arbitrary function call anyway, since that would open up a security vulnerability.

Comment: Hmmm, clever :) But not exactly what I want. I want to generate  various objects in JS having many properties like new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644). Following your way it means that I have to add to JS this second step for any such property. I would like only to add elements to PHP array and not doing this extra step. But I'm afraid that there is no better way than yours :( Anyway thank you for your idea and also for reminding me what is an array/object in JS :)

Comment: @user2042985 For multiple objects, you can match and replace the Objects with a `reviver` when `parse`'ing. See my edit under `2.` for an example.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski He's looking for a way to pass arbitrary function calls and constructors, without having to code individual handlers for them. It's not possible with PHP's native JSON module, and rightfully so because of the security flaws it creates.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me a revier :). I need to create an object in JS having properties like new google.maps.LatLng(..), new google.maps.Marker(..), new google.maps.MarkerImage(..), etc. But I think that I can figure it out how to do it using the revier. Thank you again!

Comment: @joequincy Though, the JSON can include clues as to the intended type, such as a `"$type"` property -- `"$type": "LatLng"` or `"$type": "Marker"`. Then, `if (value && value.$type === 'LatLng') ...`, etc.

Comment: Perfect comment Jonathan, I will use revier and clues for type :)